txt?_rsc Not found after deploy onto vercel
I have a lerna mono repo project which includes a nextjs app with app router.
The nextjs project works without any issues locally. I can also next build successfully.
However, when I deploy the project onto vercel, there is always showing <app-rout>.txt?_rsc=xxx not found issue.

I thought the RSC rendering issue might cause this. However, the routes are already marked as use clients on both layout.tsx & page.
I'm not sure if anybody having a similar issue can give me a hint.
Reference
Here is the monorepo FYI, the package is notifi-dapp-example
